# How to get promise to resolve for tcpPortUsed NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I am writing a NodeJS app, with a module called tcpPortUsed (https://www.npmjs.com/package/tcp-port-used), the example to use this is

```
var tcpPortUsed = require('tcp-port-used');

tcpPortUsed.check(44201, '127.0.0.1')
.then(function(inUse) {
console.log('Port 44201 usage: '+inUse);
}, function(err) {
console.error('Error on check:', err.message);
});
```

this runs async, and not what I want, I need to get response from this into a variable for my next line in the app to use. I have read up on promises and that you can use await in an async function to get it to return, however nothing seems to work with this tcpPortUsed function, I have worked out it does return a promise, but what ever I do, it never returns, the best I have got so far is promise pending into a variable, can anyone provide code to get the response returned, non-async, from this tcp-port-used function?

Comment: *"this runs async, and not what I want"* - an async check is absolutely what you want, that's not the problem. Don't write non-async code if there's a way to avoid it. Does your code not print anything at all?

Comment: Yes the code above outputs "Port 44201 usage: True" in the console, however as it async, I can't get this output into a variable. The solution I am working on is a monitoring script, so first check port is available then update part of a json request that is outputted to a webpage. The issue is when I output the json in part of my app, this function has not returned anything yet. I want it to run this function first, come back and say its in use, then do the next line of code.

Comment: The "next line of code" is inside the callback. Think about that for a moment.

Answer (score 0):

I did this in the end by using my function after this with a 2 second timeout delay on it, so the response has come back by then, only way I could get this working.